# Which version of Office 2016 I have?

Tags: microsoft-office

I'm trying to understand which version of Office 2016 I have.

I click **File** and then **Account**. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

As you could see, the build number under "About Word" button is 9029.2167.

However, when I click this button, the new window appears, and the build number in this window is different: 9029.2106. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the same version, distributed on two channels with a difference of
several days between the two.

The first was the
[Office Insider Monthly (Targeted) v1802 build 9029.2106](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/office-insider-monthly-targeted-v1802-build-9029-2106-feb-20.17634/#Office_Insider_Monthly_%28Targeted%29_v1802_build_9029_2106_Feb_20)
from Feb. 20.

The second was the
[Office 2016 & Office 365 Monthly Channel v1802 build 9029.2167](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/office-2016-office-365-monthly-channel-v1802-build-9029-2167-feb-26.11262/#Office_2016_Office_365_Monthly_Channel_v1802_build_9029_2167_Feb_26)
from Feb. 26.

The Insider version predates the Monthly version by almost one week.

What we have here is an amusing gaff by the Office developers.
The version number was entered correctly as the Monthly one
in the About Word title,
but in the dialog called up by that button it remained the Insider version.

In the official Microsoft
[Update history for Office 365 ProPlus (listed by date)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date),
there is only mentioned the Monthly version, since the Insider version
is not an official release.

Comment: "What we have here [skipped] remained the Insider version." - Yeah! And after I manually updated the Office, [the numbers are still different](https://i.imgur.com/nqbHvzf.png). Madness!

Comment: Are they updating version numbers in dialog boxes manually??? At the _very_ least this bug indicates that the version number comes from more than one single piece of metadata, which is quite silly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It means that these are separate modules that do not have common code. Agreed: This is not good practice.

Comment: @harrymc The modules should still take this metadata from a single source in the build system!

Comment: Just for the record: in Office 2013 there are 3 different builds instead of 2.

Answer (score 2):

One is the original version, the other is the update version (channel). Please refer to this article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a86b9b5a-47b1-4e7d-8759-dc0e4282369c/how-to-decode-office-365-proplus-buildversion-numbers?forum=Office2016ITPro

Please correct me if any errors in my answer.

Comment: Hmm. It is possibly correct, however the provided link is about Office 365, instead of 2016. Anyway, I upvoted it. Let's wait some time, probably someone have another answers.

Comment: I agree (& cheers, John!) I checked mine, it also presents 2 different numbers, the number "within About Word" is a smaller number than the one before "Click-to-Run".

Comment: @johnc.j. Office 2016 is simply a specific Office 365 release.  This is the correct answer